# Laravel model user status statistics

Tags: mysql, laravel, statistics

I have a User, who can create a membership. On the database, the membership has an expires_at, that I use on the frontend to display "Active" or "Inactive" depending on that time.

I want some statistics. Newly created memberships are quite easy to handle, using the created_at field.
When it comes to "active memberships", I'm not quite sure what would be the best practice.

A membership could expire in April and be continued/renewed in July, so what would be best practice?

Should I create some kind of table where statuses are stored and have a created_at and expired_at there to keep track of it, or what would you guys suggest?

Comment: Show source structure (CREATE TABLE), some sample data (INSERT INTO) and desired result for this data.

Comment: *Should I create some kind of table* Why not? fill it using triggers on base users table.

Answer (score 0):

I went with the following.

Membership model with a Many-to-Many relationship to a Status.

On the pivot table, I added a timestamp for when the status was attached to the membership.

Not only am I able to have some statistics on the active/inactive users, but I can also have status history for the user to browser on the frontend.